# String Rearrangement Algorithm in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, strings, visual-basic

Beginning programmer here (mostly engineer).  I'm making trapezoids in layers.  We begin with the small length layer, and end with the longest length layer.

I want my user to input in a desired maximum length, a desired minimum length, type of pattern (5 or 7 each) and number of layers to use.

Then the program spits out an output based on these inputs.  Here is an example with 5 plies:

**5 Layer Example:**

15 layers = MRMRM/MRMRM/MRMRM/

For a desired minimum length of 3, and varying maximum lengths, my desired output string would be:

MAX LENGTH 3: 3[MRMRM/MRMRM/MRMRM/]

MAX LENGTH 4: 3[MRMRM/MRMR] 4[M/MRMRM/]

MAX LENGTH 5: 3[MRMR] 4[M/MRMR] 5[M/MRMRM/]

MAX LENGTH 6: 3[MRMR] 4[M/MRMR] 5[M/MR] 6[MRM/]

(Separating out the M/ layers first, now splitting the MRMR into 2-char strings)

MAX LENGTH 7: 3[MRMR] 4[M/MR] 5[MR] 6[M/MR] 7[MRM/]

MAX LENGTH 8: 3[MRMR] 4[M/MR] 5[MR] 6[M/MR] 7[MR] 8[M/]

MAX LENGTH 9: 3[MR] 4[MR] 5[M/MR] 6[MR] 7[M/MR] 8[MR] 9[M/]

(Now splitting M/ from the MR strings last):

MAX LENGTH 10: 3[MR] 4[MR] 5[M/MR] 6[MR] 7[M/] 8[MR] 9[MR] 10[M/]

MAX LENGTH 11: 3[MR] 4[MR] 5[M/] 6[MR] 7[MR] 8[M/] 9[MR] 10[MR] 11[M/]

From there, it's a simple matter of taking the middle point and changing the numbers evenly between back and in front of the midpoint, evenly adding to the numbers.

I can't think of a simple algorithm to do this splitting.  Since it is slightly less material, if a split happens on an odd number (like the jump from 3-4, or 5-6), we have the split occur on the far side of the midpoint.  I envision having to do two algorithms, one for the 5 layer case and one for the 7 layer case.

Thoughts?

Comment: If I had to read that twice to understand, then maybe you should re-evaluate how the user provides the input.  If the user has to think about how to write the input, then you're not gaining any advantage.

Comment: The user just needs to input number of plies.  So they plug in the number 15, and it spits out MRMRM/MRMRM/MRMRM, broken up based on the lengths as shown.

Comment: Oh, I see, you meant output.  What do the Ms and Rs signify?

Comment: The layers designate different materials for the use in composites.  The M is a chopped strand mat layer - uniformly dispersed reinforcing fibers, that basically adhere the R layers together.  The R is a woven reinforcing layer, which does the work.  Since we build these a lot to join pieces, this is pretty common jargon in the industry.

Comment: Could you provide an example of program usage as you would want it to work?  For example, "How many trapezoids?  4   What is min length?  5  Output:  x"  Perhaps show a diagram?  I'm still having difficulty understanding how your program should work.